# Android Studio reports a bunch of errors none actually exist in my gradle.build file

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I upgraded my Android studio to 3.1 and gradle to 4.4 and after fixing all the warnings, it still reports 3 errors that just wont go away

**1**

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018
```

**2**

```
Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

**3**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preBuztransitEarthReleaseBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.0) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AppPreBuildTask.lambda$run$0(AppPreBuildTask.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AppPreBuildTask.handleArtifact(AppPreBuildTask.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.AppPreBuildTask.run(AppPreBuildTask.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

My gradle.build file is as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

// My constants removed for SO question
String MERCURY_IP_ADDRESS = ""  
String EARTH_IP_ADDRESS = "" 
String LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS = ""
String SERVER_PORT = ""
String LOCAL_SERVER_PORT = ""
String MAP_KEY = "something"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0 rc1'
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    def applicationVersion = '1.524 20180330'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        buseeta {
            storeFile file("../keystoreBuseeta.keystore")
            keyAlias "alias_name"
            storePassword "unknown"
            keyPassword "unknown"
        }

        buztransit {
            storeFile file("../keystoreBuzTransit.keystore")
            keyAlias "alias_name"
            storePassword "unknown"
            keyPassword "unknown"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {

        buztransitMercury {
            applicationId 'com.mcruiseon.buztransit'
            versionName "${applicationVersion} Mercury"
            versionCode 9
            manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                    mapsKey              : MAP_KEY,
                                    applicationTheme     : "@style/BuztransitTheme.NoActionBar"]

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.buztransit
            resValue "string", "mNoxLiveServerIP", MERCURY_IP_ADDRESS
            resValue "string", "mNoxLiveServerPort", SERVER_PORT
            resValue "string", "mNoxServerIP", MERCURY_IP_ADDRESS
            resValue "string", "mNoxServerPort", SERVER_PORT
            resValue "string", "mapKey", MAP_KEY
            resValue "string", "mNoxClinetId", ""
            resValue "string", "mSetupSalt", "removed for SO question"
            resValue "bool", "isLocalOrEmulator", "false"
        }

        buztransitEarth {
            applicationId 'com.mcruiseon.buztransit'
            versionName "${applicationVersion} Earth"
            versionCode 9

            manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                    mapsKey              : MAP_KEY,
                                    applicationTheme     : "@style/BuztransitTheme.NoActionBar"]

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.buztransit
            resValue "string", "mNoxLiveServerIP", EARTH_IP_ADDRESS
            resValue "string", "mNoxLiveServerPort", SERVER_PORT
            resValue "string", "mNoxServerIP", EARTH_IP_ADDRESS
            resValue "string", "mNoxServerPort", SERVER_PORT
            resValue "string", "mapKey", MAP_KEY
            resValue "string", "mNoxClinetId", ""
            resValue "string", "mSetupSalt", ""
            resValue "bool", "isLocalOrEmulator", "false"
        }

        buztransitLocalhost {
            applicationId 'com.mcruiseon.buztransit'
            versionName "${applicationVersion} Localhost"
            versionCode 9

            manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId: "${applicationId}",
                                    mapsKey              : MAP_KEY,
                                    applicationTheme     : "@style/BuztransitTheme.NoActionBar"]

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.buztransit
            // Here we are using two IP address, first one is only use for send otp and emails, due to
            // that it is always redirected from Live server(Like, mercury, internal, pluto).
            // Second IP address is use for all web services call.
            resValue "string", "mNoxLiveServerIP", MERCURY_IP_ADDRESS
            resValue "string", "mNoxLiveServerPort", SERVER_PORT
            resValue "string", "mNoxServerIP", LOCAL_IP_ADDRESS
            resValue "string", "mNoxServerPort", LOCAL_SERVER_PORT
            resValue "string", "mapKey", MAP_KEY
            resValue "string", "mNoxClinetId", ""
            resValue "string", "mSetupSalt", ""
            resValue "bool", "isLocalOrEmulator", "true"
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'build.gradle'
        exclude 'build.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/jersey-module-version'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    ext {
        play_services_version = '12.0.1'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    implementation project(':paymentGatewayCommons')
    implementation project(':paypal')
    implementation project(':paytm')
    implementation project(':payu')
    implementation 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0.pr1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0.pr1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${play_services_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${play_services_version}"

    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.3.0@aar'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Dependent build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ext {
        support_library_version = '27.1.0'
        firebase_version = '12.0.1'
    }
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v13:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_library_version}"

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.3-android'
    implementation 'com.applandeo:material-calendar-view:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar:stateprogressbar:0.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1'
    //implementation 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:${firebase_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${firebase_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${firebase_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:${firebase_version}"

    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'
    implementation files('libs/mnoxwebservicescommons.jar')
    implementation project(':PayPalAndroidSDK-2.15.3')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support, module: support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}
```

Dont blindly mark this question as duplicate. I have seen the duplicate questions and answers, they dont help now for `android studio 3.1`. For your reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) have been seen.

Comment: For now I have modified by versions to `26.1.0` to move ahead.

Comment: `implementation` does not handle dependencies between gradle.build files. we need to use `api` instead